# Angular JS, Components hosted in different servers

Tags: angular

I have multiple applications, each of them having similar functionalities. Example a login component or a change password component that behaves in a similar fashion across all the applications.

I want to be able to have these components being hosted as common components and have other apps use them. These same components can also be used by third party websites.

I am not sure how to go about doing something like this where angular components can become widgets that can be used directly across different applications. Any thoughts would help.

Thanks

Comment: Why not publish them on e.g. NPM?

Comment: Will that mean that the apps that are using those libraries will have to manually update them? I was thinking if can be something similar to lazy loading however on a different domain.. I know it falls under CORS category though.. wondering if there's any other design practice that we can adopt.

Comment: Yes, but on the plus side that means they get to choose when to change their dependency.